# auto scroll flickable to selected item

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to auto scroll a QML **Flickable** to selected item in a **ListView**, I have implemented a logic for calculating the position of the item and set the *contentY* property of **Flickable** to scroll to the position,
It doesn't work correctly, always scroll below the selected **Item**,
Here is the **Flickable** code:

```
// This is my selected item index I get this from my model and it is the valid index 
property var selectedServerIndex: ServersModel.getDefaultServerIndex()
```

```
Flickable {
    id: serversContainer

    anchors.top: serversMenuHeader.bottom
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.topMargin: 16

    contentHeight: col.height + col.anchors.bottomMargin
    implicitHeight: parent.height - serversMenuHeader.implicitHeight
    clip: true

    function autoScroll() {
        const eachListitemHeight = serversMenuContent.contentItem.height / serversMenuContent.count
        const totalItemsHeight = selectedServerIndex * eachListitemHeight
        contentY = totalItemsHeight - (implicitHeight / 2)
        console.log(eachListitemHeight)
        console.log(totalItemsHeight)
        console.log(implicitHeight)
        console.log(contentY)
    }
    Component.onCompleted: autoScroll()

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id: scrollBar
        policy: serversContainer.height >= serversContainer.contentHeight ? ScrollBar.AlwaysOff : ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
    }
```

The **ListView** code:

```
Column {
    id: col
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottomMargin: 32

    spacing: 16

    ButtonGroup {
        id: serversRadioButtonGroup
    }

    ListView {
        id: serversMenuContent
        width: parent.width
        height: serversMenuContent.contentItem.height

        model: ServersModel
        currentIndex: ServersModel.defaultIndex

        Connections {
            target: ServersModel
            function onDefaultServerIndexChanged(serverIndex) {
                serversMenuContent.currentIndex = serverIndex
            }
        }

        clip: true
        interactive: true

        delegate: Item {
            id: menuContentDelegate

            property variant delegateData: model

            implicitWidth: serversMenuContent.width
            implicitHeight: serverRadioButtonContent.implicitHeight

            ColumnLayout {
                id: serverRadioButtonContent

                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.rightMargin: 16
                anchors.leftMargin: 16

                spacing: 0
```

I have tried this:

```
function autoScroll() {
    const eachListitemHeight = serversMenuContent.contentItem.height / serversMenuContent.count
    const totalItemsHeight = selectedServerIndex * eachListitemHeight
    contentY = totalItemsHeight - (implicitHeight / 2)
    console.log(eachListitemHeight)
    console.log(totalItemsHeight)
    console.log(implicitHeight)
    console.log(contentY)
}
Component.onCompleted: autoScroll()
```

It doesn't scroll to the selected item, always scroll to a wrong position.

> ```
> 1- the first variable is the height of each item in the list view
> 2- second variable is the total height of the items above the selected item
> 3- the third variable is the center position of the selected item
> the console log results are:
> qml: 100 // correct
> qml: 1900 // correct because the selected item is the 20th item of the 40 items in the list
> qml: 335.20000000000005 // the implicit height of the flickable
> qml: 3184 // contentY is set to 1732.4
> ```

Comment: ListView.currentIndex has a built-in auto-scroll capability. The Flickable isn't needed. The ButtonGroup can be moved into the header section of your ListView.

Comment: please explain it more, how do I auto scroll to the selected item of the list view, I have tried setting the listView current index to the selected item index, that doesn't scroll

Comment: In your code, it won't scroll because of this line `height: serversMenuContent.contentItem.height`. If you start over, and just use something like `anchors.fill: parent`. You will see that your ListView will use its own scrolling and the `currentItem` will scroll the ListView.

Comment: okay, is there any solution to make it work while keeping this line as it?

Comment: The scrollbar works when content height > control height. Because you have content height === control height you're eliminating the scrollbar on the listview. This is the reason why it's not working for you.

Comment: you are right, I removed the column item and used anchors.fill parent and now it scrolls to the selected item, there are two problems, removing the column type removes the scrollBar withit, the second problem it takes time to scroll, is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: See ListView.highlightMoveDuration https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightMoveDuration-prop

Comment: Also set `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { width: 20; policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn }` to your `ListView`.

Comment: I set a condition for setting the scrollBar visible, I have removed the column and modified the code, now it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

ListView.currentIndex already has an built-in auto-scroll feature:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "ListView Auto-Scroll Demo"
    ListView {
        id: listView
        model: 40
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        delegate: Button { text: modelData }
        highlight: Frame { z: 3 }
        highlightMoveDuration: 1000
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 5000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        triggeredOnStart: true
        onTriggered: listView.currentIndex = Math.floor(40 * Math.random())
    }
    footer: Label { text: `CurrentIndex: ${listView.currentIndex}` }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACqHicbVHBSgNBDL33K4J4sILLqvUy4MG2CIKlisWz4266G5ydLGm2VUv/3amr021pYAby8l7mZUJVzaLwrM8NZR892kuTEXsVdoveky0Q1j0IoaQODZw80kJfCVdw1yhfvGSB52CMFZ/80mK5VW2DcgPuD45gxTk6A4M0ItZnJcsimZMLhdoKeo3FzFFtQKXBCAU9FlaDp2Gjyh7WoPippm09tmphE8klFaULJ5TvxVZhKPg2cH2MMeEljhuxSuwNXKbpzmI77dBKskRRymwwGrHOxNtYUa6lgat0D63ZUfbVUSV3bmW/FlMfaa2l9p5Rhd3G5BVluX32putLsEarB/8jjffkiwNUhYoCBfOpf1ErhyL2s3/CbmlJ1sh2Gw8+x0+4hYnVMpk7ZjkbpHDe5mJ9ztVZv9+xP2cOfg082nd0cT9vo047A6fro+9s3kKTzQ8obsnj)